# Remove a php generated table from a transactional woocommerce email

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm looking for the easiest way to remove this [tracking number table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qqp2L.jpg)from a transactional email in woocommerce.
Image attached to show what I mean.

I understand it's pulled from a function, but I don't know how to edit it without destroying the rest of the table, which I need to stay as is.

I'm not a coder, but I can follow instructions. Could tell me where I need to go and which parts to change. I could probably find my way into the function file, but I don't know how to edit it safely or what to delete/change.

```
<?php

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_details() Shows the order details table.
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_order_data() Generates structured data.
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::output_structured_data() Outputs structured data.
 * @since 2.5.0
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_meta() Shows order meta data.
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::customer_details() Shows customer details
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_address() Shows email address
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );


/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_footer() Output the email footer
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email );
```

Comment: The number is not present/set in the code you posted. Therefore your question does not contain [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: This should be editable from WooCommerce > Settings > Emails